# Execute google data flow pipeline on cloud via dataFlowRunner but not use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS for security

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-dataflow, google-secret-manager

I have a google data flow pipeline which I run from my local using the dataFlowRunner. However I have the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS stored in a file and I export it. I want to avoid storing the credentials for security reasons. Also I have saved the service-account with appropriate IAM roles in my properties file as well. Is there any way we can use Google security Manager? I have a use case to ensure code is credentials free.

Comment: The final goal is to launch your `Dataflow` job from your local machine without service account key file ?

Comment: yes. But as suggested we can try using deployment via docker

Answer (score 1):

If you launch your `Dataflow` job from your local machine, your have to export the  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var, unfortunately there is no choice in this case.

However if you launch your job via a DAG orchestrator like `Airflow` and Cloud Composer no need to pass a SA key file. The authentication is handled with `Airflow` and the SA used by `Cloud Composer`.

You can also explore other solutions with `Cloud Shell` or `Cloud Build` to launch your job, but I think it's better for the CI CD part to deploy the job and delegate the responsability of job execution to a pipeline orchestration tool like `Airflow`.

In production environment, you can also use `Dataflow Flex Template` to standardize the deployment of your `Dataflow` jobs based on a `bucket` and a `Docker` image.

In this case, if you use a tool like `Cloud Build`, no need to pass a Service Account key file.

You can check this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/ci-cd-for-dataflow-java-with-flex-templates-and-cloud-build-e3c584b8e564) I written, that shows a complete example of CI CD pipeline with `Dataflow Flex Template`.

Comment: Yes, this is a good way. There's one alternative to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that I wanted to bring up -- you can use your personal account permissions, if you authenticate through `gcloud auth application-default login`. Then there's no need for the environment variable. Check https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Bruno, it's helpful :)